# RavenDB streaming query only returns 128 results

Tags: java, indexing, ravendb

According to the documentation [here](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/java/client-api/session/querying/how-to-stream-query-results), and Ayende's (admittedly somewhat dated intro) [here](https://ayende.com/blog/161249/ravendbs-querying-streaming-unbounded-results), the only thing you need to do in order to retrieve all results from a query is to use the advanced.stream() method and then iterate through the result set.
I am doing just that, but I only get 128 results. Is there a config setting, or a session setting that needs to be activated/set ?

I certainly didn't see anything, and the RavenDB cmd window seems to confirm that I only get part of the results: "(...) Results: 128 returned out of 291 in total." 
Why ?
My code:

```
IRavenQueryable<AdministrativeArea> areaQuery = currentSession
                .query(AdministrativeArea.class, AdministrativeArea_ByNameAndWKT.class)
                .customize(new DocumentQueryCustomizationFactory().relatesToShape("WKT", mapQuadrant, net.ravendb.abstractions.indexing.SpatialOptions.SpatialRelation.WITHIN));

        try (CloseableIterator<StreamResult<AdministrativeArea>> results = currentSession.advanced().stream(areaQuery))
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (results.hasNext())
            {
                StreamResult<AdministrativeArea> adminArea = results.next();
                AdministrativeArea adma = adminArea.getDocument();
                currentlyVisibleAreas.add(adma);
                System.out.println("Just added area: " + adma.NAME_0 + adma.NAME_1 + "   ___ " + i);
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed, it is not working - pageSize=128 is send along with this request.

You can track progress of this bug here: http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-6467

Edit: Fixed in version:  3.2.2.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, looks as if it's already fixed ! Fantastic. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Fixed in 3.2.2. https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.ravendb%7Cravendb-client%7C3.2.2%7Cjar